"Nous sommes impressionnés par ses compétences." What conjugation is this?
Looks like passé composé, but the auxiliary is wrong (passé composé would be "Nous avons impressionné") and the translation looks like present continuous ("We are impressed").
Merci!

Présent de l'indicatif.

It is a simple present at the passive voice just like the English We are impressed by [...]
The latter is not a present continuous which would be We are being impressed by [...]
